# Would the same counter be used to order a slice of pizza and a whole one?

Tags: words, counters

When I order a pizza, would I use ichimai 一枚 to order a slice or the whole thing? Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As for pizza, **枚** always stands for a whole round pizza. Each cut slice is counted with [**切【き】れ**](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%88%87%E3%82%8C_%28%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8C%29/) (一【ひと】切れ, 二【ふた】切れ...).

(top: ピザ 一枚, bottom: ピザ 一切れ)
[image]

Comment: I see, one cut.

Comment: But what if your pizza gets cut into ten slices or more?

Comment: @AeonAkechi, it's still "one slice of pizza" in English, no matter how many total slices there are.  Same in Japanese, it's still ピザ一切れ no matter how many total 切れ there are from the whole ピザ一枚.

Comment: @AeonAkechi Was your question about wago or kango numerals are used? Actually, we usually switch to kango past 4...